# After installing GFCI outlet in bathroom, why won't my light fixture turn on?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, gfci

I recently installed an updated light fixture in my bathroom and swapped a standard outlet for a GFCI. Both are seemingly running through a single light switch.

Once everything was installed the light fixture stopped working.

Currently the GFCI is wired on the LOAD ends and has a green light and power.The bathroom has a second light switch that controls the fan and that works without a problem.

I’ve tried the following,

1. Replaced bulbs
2. Installed different light fixture
3. Pulled tabs up in bulb housing
4. Switched GFCI to LINE
5. Installed standard power outlet
6. Checked all connections

None of these made the light come.

Note: The light fixtures has current running to it.

I feel like I’ve run out of options!
[image][image]

Comment: 1 - Please upload pictures of any relevant junction boxes. 2 - Did the light switch *control* the receptacles previously, or only the light?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you.

Comment: Have you plugged anything into the GFCI receptacle to see if it is working? Since you are powering the light from the line and you have checked the hot conductors what about the neutral?

Comment: I honestly can’t remember if the switched controlled both the lights and outlet before, but both the light fixture and outlet only have 1 set of 3 wires (Black, White and Ground). 

Yes, I have plugged into both top and bottom ports on the outlet and they provide power.

Comment: Pictures of the junction boxes and a sketch of the wiring layout would help tremendously! [Edit] your post, then hit the "sun and mountain" icon to upload the pics.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: I’ve added a picture of the switch box. Both the light fixture and outlet are just standard 3 wire. Hope that helps?

Comment: "Note: The light fixtures has current running to it." How do you know this? How did you measure it and with what?

Comment: I used a voltage detector pen.

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks more clearly into the back of the box please?

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: @Tim -- it is, can you also post similar photos for the GFCI receptacle's box please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel That’s the confusing part. The GFCI box is very basic. Just a Hot (Black), Neutral (White) and Ground. Nothing else. I can take a picture later, I just ran out.

Comment: First of all, is this all on the same circuit? You are not allowed to do that per NEC.  The outlet should be on its own circuit.  Also get a gfci tester, which will plug into the outlet and will tell you whether it's wired correctly.

Comment: @cryptic0 -- the NEC permits a circuit to serve both lighting and receptacles for a single bahtroom though

Comment: It is on the same circuit. What’s odd is the switch box has 4 sets of wires entering it. All these comments aside, I never changed the wire set up. Simply installed a new switch, new light fixture and replaced an outlet with a GFCI. When I was trouble shooting, I simply reinstalled a standard outlet and the light still wouldn’t work...